# Detecting mouse click on div with Javascript without side-effects

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect whenever someone clicks in a div (essentially I want to know when a user is interacting with a section of text on my site, be that by selecting some text or clicking on a link), but I don't want to interfere with what the user is doing.

If I put a onmousedown or onclick event on the div it ends up breaking selection, links, etc. Is there any way to catch these events without causing any interference ?

Comment: Unless you specifically have code that interferes (such as setting `event.cancelBubble`, calling `event.stopPropagation()` or returning true (or something truth-y) you code shouldn't be interfering. Can you show a specific example?

Answer (score 11):

Onmousedown or onclick shouldn't interfere with anything as long as it **doesn't** `return false;`.

You can do this:

```
document.getElementById("spy-on-me").onmousedown = function () {
    console.log("User moused down");
    return true; // Not needed, as long as you don't return false
};
```

If you have other scripts that are attaching behaviour via this method on the page, then to prevent overriding them you can do:

```
var spyElement = document.getElementById("spy-on-me");
var oldMousedown = spyElement.onmousedown;
spyElement.onmousedown = function () {
    console.log("User moused down");
    if(oldMousedown) oldMousedown();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I suspect you are currently returning `false` at the end of the event binding, just don't do that or any of the things in this binding:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

If you do not do any of these three things, jQuery will not stop the event from  bubbling up to the browser.

**Edit:** Sorry didn't realise it was a plain JavaScript question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use do it by adding a event listener as well

```
var myNode= document.querySelector('.imagegrid'); 
myNode.addEventListener("click",function(e){    
 alert(e.target+" clicked"); 
});
```

A similar example is demonstrated [here](http://bit.ly/DEcClickSOF)

Answer (score -2):

Can't you simply add a click event to the div?

```
<div id="secretDiv" (click)="secretDivClick()">
```

then on your component:

```
secretDivClick() {
console.log('clicked');
}
```